# Maneira de não quebrar uma linha ao criar um elemento input

Tags: html, css, quebras-de-linha, css-display

Comecei um projeto em HTML, CSS e JavaScript e me deparei com a seguinte situação: quando crio um elemento input no html ele automaticamente pula uma linha em relação aos outros elementos, gostaria de saber um jeito para que esse input ficasse na mesma linha de outros dois elementos.(no caso, um label e um span).

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input.command')
const dir = document.querySelector('span.dir')

let currentDir = "D:\\Users\\currentUser"

dir.innerHTML = currentDir
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #282A36;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Fira Code";
}

input.command{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Fira Code";
    background-color: #282A36;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 0px;,
    text-align: center;
}
span, label{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Fira Code";
    background-color: #282A36;
    outline: none;
}
span, label, input{
    display: inline-flexbox;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Ice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="dir"></span>
    <label class="incode"></label>
    $<input class="command" size="123">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deve ser definido um `width` para seus input.

```css
main{
  width: 100%
}
input:text{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</main>
```

---

Outro método seria usando [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">

  <label>Nome: </label>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</main>
```

Comment: por se tratar de um terminal, como faria para fazer com que, ao ultrapassar o limite da linha, ele passe a mostrar o texto na linha de baixo?

Comment: Nesse caso, teria que ser feito em javascript pra atribuir `width = 100%` quando o input receber X quantidade de caracteres.

Answer (score -2):

use class="col-2 ou 3", e verifique se consegue alinhar suas tags como deseja, o limite do col é 12, então distribua de modo que caiba tudo dentro do limite, assim ficarão na mesma linha

Comment: mas em que parte do código seria implementado esse class="col-3"??

Comment: Por exemplo: <body>
    <span class="dir col-4"></span>
    <label class="incode col-4"></label>
    $<input class="command col-4" size="123">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body> 

As 3 tags ficariam na mesma linha, pois estão dentro do limite '12' por linha, entendeu? Veja se funciona.

Comment: Você também pode criar uma <div class="col-4"> </div> em cada "input/label" para organizar, aí você agrupa suas div's dentro de um outra que aglobara todas elas sendo "col-12"

Comment: testei esse método e parece que ele considera o 'col-4' como nome da classe.

Comment: Faz assim:<body>
                    <div class="col-12"> 
                       <div class="col-4">
                          <span class="dir"></span>
                        </div>

                         <div class="col-4">
                              <label class="incode"></label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-4">
                            $<input class="command" size="123">
                         </div>
                  </div>
                </body>